# strange behavior of constant 'e' in Python

Tags: python

I experienced very strange behavior in Python.
I am an electronics engineer. So I use constant 'e' in the equation sometimes.

```
from math import *

try:
    eval('print(log(e))')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    eval('print(long(e))')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    eval('log(e)')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

the output is

```
1.0
name 'long' is not defined
name 'e' is not defined
```

I miss typed log(e) to long(e). Before that equation log(e) works well, but the second log(e) after long(e), the Python does not understand 'e'.

Do you have any idea what's going on there?

I am using python3.8.2 on Windows.

Comment: You also name the *exception* `e`. Also you should rarely if ever use wildcard imports.

Comment: change "Exception as e" to "Exception as err" (and e to err in print) and try again?

Comment: Wow. You are correct. I change "Exception as e" to "Exception as err", it works fine.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I am making simple text based calculator. So eval is easy to implement that.
I heard that the 'eval' is a little dangerous. But the user is only me. :)

Comment: @Jens be *very* careful when editing code in questions - in this case, if an error isn't thrown the except block isn't entered and *e doesn't get shadowed*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting:

```
except Exception as e:
```

*shadows* the imported name from `math`, but **only** if the `except` block is entered (i.e. an error is thrown). The reference is cleared outside the `except` block, but that removes *any* reference to `e`. It's equivalent to:

```
>>> from math import e
>>> e
2.718281828459045
>>> e = "foo"  # shadow the imported name
>>> e
'foo'
>>> del e  # try to return to previous value
>>> e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

This is also mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) for the `try` statement (emphasis mine):

> When an exception has been assigned using `as target`, **it is cleared
>   at the end of the except clause**. This is as if
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     foo
> ```
>
> was translated to
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     try:
>         foo
>     finally:
>         del N
> ```

The simplest fixes are to either:

- rename the exception to something other than `e`; or
- `import math` then refer to `math.e` (note wildcard imports are [discouraged by PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)).

Answer (score 0):

So we are shadowing the variable `e` from the `math` module. In the second `try-catch` you are catching the exception as `e`, so, the `e` from `math` module get replaced by this `e` (exception).

You should always keep in mind that never use a variable name that is already being used by some module that you are importing etc. For example, don't use variable name `list` as it will shadow the built-in type `list` and you program will behave strangely.

In order to fix this problem, replace this:

```
except Exception as e:
```

to this:

```
except Exception as ex:
```