# Assigning names to errors in except blocks and using them later

Tags: python, exception, scope

This code snippet works:

```
try:
    raise Exception('oh no!')
except Exception as e:
    error = e

print(error) # prints "oh no!"
```

This code snippet fails:

```
try:
    raise Exception('oh no!')
except Exception as e:
    e = e

print(e) # NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

What's going on?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61318284/3001761. Python clears the target name, whatever's assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python,

```
except Exception as e:
    error = e
```

is equivalent to

```
except Exception as e:
    try:
        error = e
    finally:
        del e
```

I.e., `e` is deleted after the `except` block. If you assign `e` to `e`, it will be deleted - however, this is only true for the alias. If you assign it to `error`, `e` will also be deleted but not `error`.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Comment: That's unexpected. It means I can't even do `e = 'hello'` in the `except` block like I would normally reassign names.

Comment: @actual_panda correct, and per the question I linked it'll clear stuff that was defined before the try, too. It shouldn't be unexpected, because this is how the try statement is documented.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ouch, that means you have to be very careful with the name you choose in the `... as <name>` part. I wonder if this couldn't be done better.