What is the scope of a name defined using a Python with block?
I am trying to update a test script written in Python.  It has a construct I do not understand:
        with RequestTrap(self.channel) as trap:
            request = self.task[0].svc.create({'task_use': TaskUse.STANDARD})
        request.request_data.attribute_structures.task_use.idnum = attr

        # Verify the request will return an unexpected attribute in list error.
        try:
            trap.response
        except ResponseError as err:
            test.eq(err.generalStatus, CipGeneralStatus.UNEXPECTED_ATTRIBUTE_IN_LIST)
            test.eq(err.extendedStatus, None)
        else:
            test.logfail("Class level - Incorrect error response, expecting"
                         "UNEXPECTED_ATTRIBUTE_IN_LIST: attribute=%d" % attr)

What is the scope of the name "trap"?  It looks to me like it should only be defined in the  with block, but it is not even used in that block.  The RequestTrap class does have an attribute named "request".  Why is "trap" still defined outside the with block?

with blocks don't define lexical scopes, see the linked duplicates. But using an exited context manager is unusual because it's in a state not usually meant for use. ThisRequestTrap is more of an exception.

Although the first duplicate doesn't mention except Foo as bar where the name bar is deleted at the end of the block.

For that particular gotcha see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61318358/3001761
